# Setup VNet integration for an Azure App Service (web app) via Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to setup VNet integration for an Azure App Service (web app) via terraform, and the below is the code I have been using:

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "network_app_wtier_subnet" {
  name                 = "App-Web-tier"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.network_rg.name
  virtual_network_name = local.vnet_name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.1.1.0/27"]

  delegation {
    name = "delegation"

    service_delegation {
        actions = [
            "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/action",
            "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action"
          ]
        name    = "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms"
      }
  }
}
```

... and I am getting the following error:

```
> Error: expected delegation.0.service_delegation.0.name to be one of 
> [Microsoft.ApiManagement/service 
> Microsoft.AzureCosmosDB/clusters
> Microsoft.BareMetal/AzureVMware Microsoft.BareMetal/CrayServers
> Microsoft.Batch/batchAccounts
> Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups
> Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces Microsoft.DBforMySQL/flexibleServers
> Microsoft.DBforMySQL/serversv2
> Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/flexibleServers
> Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/serversv2
> Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/singleServers
> Microsoft.HardwareSecurityModules/dedicatedHSMs
> Microsoft.Kusto/clusters
> Microsoft.Logic/integrationServiceEnvironments
> Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces Microsoft.Netapp/volumes
> Microsoft.Network/managedResolvers
> Microsoft.PowerPlatform/vnetaccesslinks
> Microsoft.ServiceFabricMesh/networks Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances
> Microsoft.Sql/servers Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/streamingJobs
> Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments
> Microsoft.Web/serverFarms], got Microsoft.Web/serverfarms
>     │
>     │   with module.paired_regions_network.azurerm_subnet.network_app_wtier_subnet,
>     │   on modules/network/main.tf line 49, in resource "azurerm_subnet" "network_app_wtier_subnet":
>     │   49:         name    = "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms"
```

The error itself is contradictive : so, it expects `Microsoft.Web/serverFarms`, gets `Microsoft.Web/serverFarms`, but still errors?

Any idea how can I fix this?

---

**EDIT**

The configuration I was using when I initially wrote the post is the following:

```
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" { }

  required_version = ">= 0.14"
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">=2.50.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Which should accommodate for any updates, I guess. Right?

Updating it to more recent versions (below) resulted in the same error.

```
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" { }

  required_version = ">= 0.15"
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">=2.72.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: looks all good to me. are you on the latest provider version?

Comment: Thanks for your input! I updated the answer with more information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, I could repro it - and fix it. It's case-sensitive... Use `"Microsoft.Web/serverFarms"` instead (uppercase F)

Comment: OMG... Indeed, I was able to finish running terraform plan changing to upperface F :) thank you so much!